# Build a shortcut for string to be used as an argument later

Tags: expansion, xparse, parsing

I need to pass the result of a macro as a string to another macro (I'm using `xparse`).  Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\TwoVarFunction}{mm}{#1 is a #2}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{this;string}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foobar}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}m}{\TwoVarFunction #1}

\begin{document}
\foo

\TwoVarFunction{this}{string}

\foobar{this;string}

\foobar{\foo}
\end{document}
```

I expected the output of the last three lines to be the same in the pdf (namely `this is a string`).  However, `\foo` is not being parsed as an input to `\foobar` the way I expected; the actual output of `\foobar{\foo}` is "`this;string is a -No Value-`".

Please (1) explain why LaTeX is not reading my mind, and (2) help me find a way to process `\foo` so that the output is the same.

Comment: `\foobar` looks for a semicolon in its argument and finds none, because the argument isn't expanded until later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an argument is absorbed, it is not processed in any way (unless a processor is applied), so with your code `\foo` is seen and it doesn't contain a semicolon at the upper level.

You can define your own processor. An `xparse` argument processor works by setting `\ProcessedArgument` to the desired token list; in this case you need to expand once the argument, with the help of `\tl_set:No` (`o` for “once”).

Thus the chain is first apply `\ExpandArg`, then `\SplitArgument`, so

> `\foo` → this;string → {this}{string}

and this is what `#1` means in the replacement text and seen by `\TwoVarFunction`.

Without `\ExpandArg`, no semicolon would be seen at the outer level and we'd get

> `\foo` → {\foo}{-NoValue-}

because this is how `\SplitArgument` normalizes the output when less than the stated number of separators is seen.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__user_expand_arg:n
 {
  \tl_set:No \ProcessedArgument { #1 }
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \ExpandArg \__user_expand_arg:n

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\TwoVarFunction}{mm}{#1 is a #2}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foobar}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{;}}>{\ExpandArg}m}{%
  \TwoVarFunction #1%
}

\newcommand{\foo}{this;string}

\begin{document}
\foo

\TwoVarFunction{this}{string}

\foobar{this;string}

\foobar{\foo}
\end{document}
```

Note that you have to define `\foo` with `\newcommand`, because `\NewDocumentCommand` would introduce a (large) number of layers until the expansion is `this;arg`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I've accepted this answer.  If it isn't asking too much, could you make some comments in the code as to what is going on between `\ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff` ?  I don't follow how this is fixing the issue.

Comment: @User12345 I added some explanation.