# How to expand a macro argument into a string, remove all the spaces, then append and prepend the string inside a \NewDocumentCommand macro definition?

Tags: spacing, xparse, strings, xpatch

#### *I want to expand a macro argument into a string, remove all the spaces, then append and prepend the string inside a \NewDocumentCommand macro definition.*

Here's my MWE using LuaLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,DIV=12]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}

    % \ExpandArg (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515425)
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__user_expand_arg:n
 {
  \tl_set:No \ProcessedArgument { #1 }
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \ExpandArg \__user_expand_arg:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

    % \RemoveSpaces (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87510)
\makeatletter
\def\RemoveSpaces#1{\zap@space#1 \@empty}
\makeatother

    % \foo, \foobar, and \xy
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{>{\ExpandArg} m}{%
    \renewcommand{\foobar}{+\RemoveSpaces{#1}.}
    \xpatchcmd{\foobar}{+x-y.}{++xx--yy..}{}{} % check if there's a '+x-y.' w/o any spaces, then replace it with '++xx--yy..'
    \foobar % print the output
}
\newcommand{\foobar}{}
\newcommand{\xy}{ x - y }

\begin{document}\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}\Large%
    \[\foo{\xy}\] % if all the spaces are removed, it should print the output as '++xx--yy..' and not '+x-y.'
\end{document}
```

*Why does this not work?* I think the problem might be that I don't really understand how [`\RemoveSpaces`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87510) works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\zap@space` works by full expansion, so has to be used inside of an `\edef` or `\expanded` context. Your `\foobar`'s content will not be expanded inside of `\renewcommand`, so it will be exactly what you fill in there. The macro `\xy` is expanded once, leaving `␣x␣-␣y␣`, and then you assign that to `\foobar`, which will contain `+\RemoveSpaces{␣x␣-␣y␣}.` now, which doesn't match your search string `+x-y.`.

Notice however that `\zap@space` has several historic limitations: It has to be used inside of a full-expansion context, and it might remove braces you want to keep.

The following defines an argument processor that zaps all spaces without such limitations, and hence you can simply use `#1` inside your `\renewcommand`.

```
\documentclass[oneside,DIV=12]{scrbook}

\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}

    % \ExpandArg (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515425)
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__user_expand_arg:n
 {
  \tl_set:No \ProcessedArgument { #1 }
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \ExpandArg \__user_expand_arg:n
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__user_arg_zap_spaces:n #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \ProcessedArgument {#1}
    \tl_remove_all:Nn \ProcessedArgument { ~ }
  }
\cs_set_eq:NN \ArgZapSpaces \__user_arg_zap_spaces:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

    % \foo, \foobar, and \xy
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{>{\ArgZapSpaces}>{\ExpandArg} m}{%
    \renewcommand{\foobar}{+#1.}
    \xpatchcmd{\foobar}{+x-y.}{++xx--yy..}{}{} % check if there's a '+x-y.' w/o any spaces, then replace it with '++xx--yy..'
    \foobar % print the output
}
\newcommand{\foobar}{}
\newcommand{\xy}{ x - y }

\begin{document}\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}\Large%
    \[\foo{\xy}\] % if all the spaces are removed, it should print the output as '++xx--yy..' and not '+x-y.'
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Just for completeness, this is how `\zap@space` works:

`\zap@space` is defined as

```
\def\zap@space#1 #2{#1\ifx#2\@empty\else\expandafter\zap@space\fi#2}
```

So it reads everything up to a space as `#1`, and outputs this. Additionally it reads one token (or braced group, which would be unbraced by this) and compares that to `\@empty` (which is the end marker in your `\RemoveSpaces`). If `#2` isn't `\@empty` `\zap@space` calls itself. `#2` is reinserted at the end (and if it's `\@empty` will expand to nothing so doesn't hurt). The approach taken can only work in full expansion, as `#1` is always put before the next call to `\zap@space`, so we can't expand from the left until `\zap@space` is done (except in the nonsensical case that `#1` only expands to nothing).

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your answer.