# How to redefine math mode accent macros (\bar, \hat, etc.) to kern only specifically for \mathbb and \mathcal inputs but behave normally otherwise

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, mathcal, blackboard, calligraphy

Inspired by [David Carlisle's answer and comment from my previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666905/), I wanted to see if I could try and redefine the math mode accent macros (`\bar`, `\hat`, `\dot`, etc.) to kern specifically for `\mathbb` and `\mathcal` inputs because I want to use AMS blackboard bold and Computer Modern calligraphic respectively instead of Latin Modern's in `LuaTeX` with `unicode-math`.

Here's my MWE:

[image: MWE]

```
% !TEX program = lualatex

% DOCUMENT CLASS
\documentclass[11pt,preview,varwidth,%
border={3pt 5pt 3pt 5pt}% left bottom right top
]{standalone}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
    \let\lmmathbb\mathbb % Latin Modern blackboard bold
    \let\lmmathcal\mathcal % Latin Modern calligraphic
    \DeclareMathAlphabet{\amsmathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n} % AMS blackboard bold
    \DeclareMathAlphabet{\cmmathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n} % Computer Modern calligraphic

% START OF DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
    Latin Modern's \verb|\mathbb| & : & \(\bar{\lmmathbb{A}} \hat{\lmmathbb{A}} \vec{\lmmathbb{A}} \dot{\lmmathbb{A}} \ddot{\lmmathbb{A}}\) \\
    \(\cmmathcal{AMS}\)'s \verb|\mathbb| (with \textit{unkerned} accents) & : & \(\bar{\amsmathbb{A}} \hat{\amsmathbb{A}} \vec{\amsmathbb{A}} \dot{\amsmathbb{A}} \ddot{\amsmathbb{A}}\) \\
    Latin  Modern's \verb|\mathcal| & : & \(\bar{\lmmathcal{A}} \hat{\lmmathcal{A}} \vec{\lmmathcal{A}} \dot{\lmmathcal{A}} \ddot{\lmmathcal{A}}\) \\
    Computer Modern's \verb|\mathcal| (with \textit{unkerned} accents) & : & \(\bar{\cmmathcal{A}} \hat{\cmmathcal{A}} \vec{\cmmathcal{A}} \dot{\cmmathcal{A}} \ddot{\cmmathcal{A}}\)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
% END OF DOCUMENT
```

I want to achieve the following:

[image: Desired Result]

```
.
.
.
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
    Latin Modern's \verb|\mathbb| & : & \(\bar{\lmmathbb{A}} \hat{\lmmathbb{A}} \vec{\lmmathbb{A}} \dot{\lmmathbb{A}} \ddot{\lmmathbb{A}}\) \\
    \(\cmmathcal{AMS}\)'s \verb|\mathbb| (with \textit{kerned} accents) & : & \(\bar{\amsmathbb{A}} \hat{\amsmathbb{A}} \vec{\amsmathbb{A}} \dot{\amsmathbb{A}} \ddot{\amsmathbb{A}}\) \\
    Latin  Modern's \verb|\mathcal| & : & \(\bar{\lmmathcal{A}} \hat{\lmmathcal{A}} \vec{\lmmathcal{A}} \dot{\lmmathcal{A}} \ddot{\lmmathcal{A}}\) \\
    Computer Modern's \verb|\mathcal| (with \textit{kerned} accents) & : & \(\bar{\cmmathcal{A}} \hat{\cmmathcal{A}} \vec{\cmmathcal{A}} \dot{\cmmathcal{A}} \ddot{\cmmathcal{A}}\)
\end{tabular}
.
.
.
```

### How can I redefine `\bar`, `\hat`, `\vec`, `\dot`, and `\ddot` efficiently to achieve the desired result above for `\amsmathbb` and `\cmmathcal` inputs? (With the requirement that they behave normally otherwise)

Comment: It seems that there is a bug in LaTeX's Unicode math. If you remove `\usepackage{unicode-math}` and use simply `$\hat{\cal A}$` then the result is correct. Moreover, I tried OpTeX with Unicode math and with LatinModern-Math main font and \cal from Computer Modern (see OpTeX trick http://petr.olsak.net/optex/optex-tricks.html#orical ) and the result is correct too.

Comment: There’s a preliminary problem: are you sure your readers will be able to distinguish between CM and LM calligraphic letters in the same document? The situation is even worse for blackboard bold.

Comment: @egreg I don't plan to actually use Latin Modern for either blackboard bold or calligraphic letters in my documents, I just simply wanted to be able to still access them for accessing sake (the MWE is used to show the differences when using accents). My issue is only with the kerning of accents when using AMS's blackboard bold and CM's calligraphic fonts.

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach but I do not know whether it is "efficient" or not and any feedback would be much appreciated.

[image: My Approach]

```
% !TEX program = lualatex

% DOCUMENT CLASS
\documentclass[11pt,preview,varwidth,%
border={3pt 5pt 3pt 5pt}% left bottom right top
]{standalone}

% PACKAGES
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
    \let\lmmathbb\mathbb % Latin Modern blackboard bold
    \let\lmmathcal\mathcal % Latin Modern calligraphic
    \DeclareMathAlphabet{\amsmathbb}{U}{msb}{m}{n} % AMS blackboard bold
    \DeclareMathAlphabet{\cmmathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n} % Computer Modern calligraphic
\usepackage{xstring} % For \string and \IfSubStr

    % \shiftmath (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/666905/)
\newcommand{\shiftmath}[3]{#1{{\mkern-#2mu}#3{\mkern#2mu}}}

    % \amsmathbbkerning and \cmmathcalkerning
\newcommand{\amsmathbbkerning}{-2}
\newcommand{\cmmathcalkerning}{1.5}

% \ArgZapSpaces (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/652826/)
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__user_arg_zap_spaces:n #1
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \ProcessedArgument {#1}
    \tl_remove_all:Nn \ProcessedArgument { ~ }
  }
\cs_set_eq:NN \ArgZapSpaces \__user_arg_zap_spaces:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

% \bar redefinition
\let\oldbar\bar
\NewDocumentCommand{\newbar}{>{\ArgZapSpaces}m}{%
    \IfSubStr{\string#1}{\string\amsmathbb}{%
        \shiftmath{\oldbar}{\amsmathbbkerning}{#1}  % if \amsmathbb
    }{%
        \IfSubStr{\string#1}{\string\cmmathcal}{%
            \shiftmath{\oldbar}{\cmmathcalkerning}{#1} % if \cmmathcal
        }{%
            \oldbar{#1} % if neither \amsmathbb nor \cmmathcal
        }
    }
}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\bar{\newbar}}

    % \hat redefinition
\let\oldhat\hat
\NewDocumentCommand{\newhat}{>{\ArgZapSpaces}m}{%
    \IfSubStr{\string#1}{\string\amsmathbb}{%
        \shiftmath{\oldhat}{\amsmathbbkerning}{#1}  % if \amsmathbb
    }{%
        \IfSubStr{\string#1}{\string\cmmathcal}{%
            \shiftmath{\oldhat}{\cmmathcalkerning}{#1} % if \cmmathcal
        }{%
            \oldhat{#1} % if neither \amsmathbb nor \cmmathcal
        }
    }
}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\hat{\newhat}}

    % \vec redefinition
\let\oldvec\vec
\NewDocumentCommand{\newvec}{>{\ArgZapSpaces}m}{%
    \IfSubStr{\string#1}{\string\amsmathbb}{%
        \shiftmath{\oldvec}{\amsmathbbkerning}{#1}  % if \amsmathbb
    }{%
        \IfSubStr{\string#1}{\string\cmmathcal}{%
            \shiftmath{\oldvec}{\cmmathcalkerning}{#1} % if \cmmathcal
        }{%
            \oldvec{#1} % if neither \amsmathbb nor \cmmathcal
        }
    }
}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\vec{\newvec}}

    % \dot redefinition
\let\olddot\dot
\NewDocumentCommand{\newdot}{>{\ArgZapSpaces}m}{%
    \IfSubStr{\string#1}{\string\amsmathbb}{%
        \shiftmath{\olddot}{\amsmathbbkerning}{#1}  % if \amsmathbb
    }{%
        \IfSubStr{\string#1}{\string\cmmathcal}{%
            \shiftmath{\olddot}{\cmmathcalkerning}{#1} % if \cmmathcal
        }{%
            \olddot{#1} % if neither \amsmathbb nor \cmmathcal
        }
    }
}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\dot{\newdot}}

    % \ddot redefinition
\let\oldddot\ddot
\NewDocumentCommand{\newddot}{>{\ArgZapSpaces}m}{%
    \IfSubStr{\string#1}{\string\amsmathbb}{%
        \shiftmath{\oldddot}{\amsmathbbkerning}{#1}  % if \amsmathbb
    }{%
        \IfSubStr{\string#1}{\string\cmmathcal}{%
            \shiftmath{\oldddot}{\cmmathcalkerning}{#1} % if \cmmathcal
        }{%
            \oldddot{#1} % if neither \amsmathbb nor \cmmathcal
        }
    }
}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\ddot{\newddot}}

% START OF DOCUMENT
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
    Latin Modern's \verb|\mathbb| & : & \(\bar{\lmmathbb{A}} \hat{\lmmathbb{A}} \vec{\lmmathbb{A}} \dot{\lmmathbb{A}} \ddot{\lmmathbb{A}}\) \\
    \(\cmmathcal{AMS}\)'s \verb|\mathbb| (with \textit{unkerned} accents) & : & \(\oldbar{\amsmathbb{A}} \oldhat{\amsmathbb{A}} \oldvec{\amsmathbb{A}} \olddot{\amsmathbb{A}} \oldddot{\amsmathbb{A}}\) \\
    \(\cmmathcal{AMS}\)'s \verb|\mathbb| (with \textit{kerned} accents) & : & \(\bar{\amsmathbb{A}} \hat{\amsmathbb{A}} \vec{\amsmathbb{A}} \dot{\amsmathbb{A}} \ddot{\amsmathbb{A}}\) \\
    Latin  Modern's \verb|\mathcal| & : & \(\bar{\lmmathcal{A}} \hat{\lmmathcal{A}} \vec{\lmmathcal{A}} \dot{\lmmathcal{A}} \ddot{\lmmathcal{A}}\) \\
    Computer Modern's \verb|\mathcal| (with \textit{unkerned} accents) & : & \(\oldbar{\cmmathcal{A}} \oldhat{\cmmathcal{A}} \oldvec{\cmmathcal{A}} \olddot{\cmmathcal{A}} \oldddot{\cmmathcal{A}}\) \\
    Computer Modern's \verb|\mathcal| (with \textit{kerned} accents) & : & \(\bar{\cmmathcal{A}} \hat{\cmmathcal{A}} \vec{\cmmathcal{A}} \dot{\cmmathcal{A}} \ddot{\cmmathcal{A}}\)
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
% END OF DOCUMENT
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: it's bit odd to use xstring in l3 code,  I doubt the package adds any functionality here also as commented on your last question, don't use `\let` on latex commands

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not personally proficient in l3 code as I haven't read the documentations yet and most of my knowledge comes from reading TeX.SX answers, if you don't mind could you please show me how to improve the solution? Thank you.